# The [android] tag is showing up on my question list when it isn't selected

Tags: bug, tags, new-nav

For some reason, the site is serving me questions that have the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag. It only happens sometimes, like when I click the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag under favorites, but then when I click elsewhere (like deleting the temporary custom CSS tab that is auto-created and selecting my own complex CSS saved tab), the problem persists:

[image]

I've double checked, and I don't have that tag in my custom filter. I also have tried clicking the home tab, refreshing, deleting any new/unsaved custom tabs, etc.

The URL I see when on the view in my screenshot is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css and not javascript and not jquery and not angularjs and not php?filter=need-answers
```

Have androids taken over Stack Overflow?

I'm on Firefox 46.0.1.

Comment: Same for Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m

Comment: [Same here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324411/bug-with-tag-filtered-tab-completely-unrelated-questions-are-listed)

Comment: I think the filter is broken, since three questions about this were posted in the last 15 mins: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324410/newest-questions-order-bug and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324411/bug-with-tag-filtered-tab-completely-unrelated-questions-are-listed

Comment: I randomly saw only JQuery questions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b yesterday.

Comment: What http://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current says?

Comment: @Braiam Hm? That page shows that I prefer to avoid [tag:android] questions. Though the page was last updated over two years ago...

Comment: The updated time is just like that http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238638/213575

Comment: @Braiam Okay, that still doesn't explain how it's related to my bug report. The tag seems to be random, and in my case, is a tag that I tend to *ignore*.

Comment: The system could have predicted that you can answer an android question

Comment: @Braiam I *could* answer a question in pretty much any tag. Why would the system predict that I could answer one in [tag:android], one of my least-answered tags, and therefore give me *only* [tag:android] questions? Are you suggesting that there was a critical error in the prediction algorithms that was so monumental it decided to flood my page with questions of a random tag from my 5 least-answered tags?

Comment: Or that the logic is flipped