# Newest Questions Order Bug

Tags: bug, questions, sorting

I was looking at the newest `SQL`-tagged questions just a few moments ago, and clicked the `Newest` tab to order them, and got the following:

[image: Weird sort order]

Last time I checked, it was 2016, not 2012.  I tried refreshing the page several times, and it either gives me the same results, the correct results, or another random point in time.

It's not in the screenshot, but this was taken today (`2016-06-03 11:50 EDT`), and this *is* the first page of the results.

Comment: I can reproduce it with `&pagesize=50`, but without an explicit page size, I get the newest questions. - Well, I can no longer reproduce it.