# Bug with tag filtered tab, completely unrelated questions are listed

Tags: bug

I've noticed this within the recent half hour. I'm navigating back to my tag filtered tab by clicking the tag ([c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) and the tab lists completely unrelated questions ([jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)):

[image]

Comment: This looks like the same issue as [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324409/the-android-tag-is-showing-up-on-my-question-list-when-it-isnt-selected) but with different tags.

Comment: @Kendra Probably yes.